# Save chosen background image to localstorage and show that automatically when refreshing site

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I made an options.html which is basically my popup

and when you click #clickme1 it triggers an event at /popup/1.js which is

```js
function hello() {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    file: '/alert/1.js'
  });
}

document.getElementById('clickme1').addEventListener('click', hello);


and my / alert / 1. js looks like this:

  alert("Background set!");

var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://www.toptal.com/designers/subtlepatterns/patterns/curls.png)';
```

```css
body {
  background: #232526;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #414345, #232526);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #414345, #232526);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  width: 410px;
}

p {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #000;
  text-align: center;
}

.myDiv {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #000;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  color: gray;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #000;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  color: white;
}

#clickme1 {
  background-image: url(https://www.toptal.com/designers/subtlepatterns/patterns/curls.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  height: 134px;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 134px;
}

#clickme2 {
  background-image: url(https://66.media.tumblr.com/3cca60810de972cc08c4a5ac40b690df/tumblr_inline_nk1lmq0ZgB1s9yrmw.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 100%;
  height: 134px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 134px;
}

#clickme3 {
  background-image: url(https://78.media.tumblr.com/04ff549b92bb99db8ad725a83e288030/tumblr_inline_n258pty5wY1qhwjx8.gif);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 100%;
  height: 134px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 134px;
}

#clickme4 {
  background-image: url(http://brainlava.com/admin/assets/SP2013BGPattern.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 100%;
  height: 134px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 134px;
}

#clickme5 {
  background-image: url(https://background-tiles.com/overview/black/textures/large/5013.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 100%;
  height: 134px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 134px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
    To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
    To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
    and open the template in the editor.
    -->
<html>

<head>
  <title>Dark Theme Options</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>

<body>

  <body>
    <p>This extension will simply change how CryptoKitties look</p>
    <p>It won't do anything with your account</p>
    <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
      <img src="/icons/moon128.png" style="width: 128px; height: 128px;" />
    </div>
    <h2>Privacy Policy</h2>
    <p>This extension does not store/save/transmit any data in/out of your computer. It only changes how CryptoKitties is looking</p>
    <p><a href="https://kittyscripts.weebly.com">https://kittyscripts.weebly.com</a></p>
    <p>czukorhaver@gmail.com</p>
    <div class="myDiv">
      <p2>Open <a href="http://cryptokitties.co" target="_blank">this page</a> and then click the background down below that you want to set<br><br></p2>
    </div>
    <!--First background-->
    <button id="clickme1"></button>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/popup/1.js"></script>
    <!--Second background-->
    <button id="clickme2"></button>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/popup/2.js"></script>
    <!--Third background-->
    <button id="clickme3"></button>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/popup/3.js"></script>
    <!--Fourth background-->
    <button id="clickme4"></button>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/popup/4.js"></script>
    <!--Fifth background-->
    <button id="clickme5"></button>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/popup/5.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

If you click on clickme2 it does the same, there's just a different image in alert.js.

It all works perfectly, but when you refresh the page this page applies the background image to, the background image disappears and its the default white one again. Is there any way to somehow save the chosen image to localstorage and automatically apply that when the user is refreshing the page?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Make one js file for our popup window, that just saves the background choice.
In your popup.js do something like this:

```
//Get the desired background, let's just say you have prefixed options
document.getElementById('background1').addEventListener('click', function (event) {

chrome.storage.local.set({background:"background1.png"});
}
```

Then make a javascript file that runs on every page of the desired website, like this (https://www.google.com/*)

```
chrome.storage.local.get([background], function (result) {
document.body.style = "background: URL(chrome-extension://"+chrome.runtime.id+"/"+background+";";
});
```

Hope that helps.